# Kubuntu 19.10: How to make K remember accounts for windows network shares?

Tags: networking, kubuntu, shared-folders

Kubuntu 19.10 + kde PPA. Latest updates.

How can I make Kubuntu remember windows network share logins?

I can only set one global windows share account is Settings.

What if I have several accounts for different windows network drives?

Where should I put them?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

if you open **dolphin**, then you open a windows share like this:
smb://mydomain%5Cmyusername@machine.name.com/sharename$/

And then you enter your credentials and click at "remember password", is done.

Then you can add a link at the left of Dolphin to make easier to remember the share URL.

cheers!

Comment: Thanx but 

"click at "remember password"

That's the problem. It doesn't offer me to save the password. There is no such option.

Comment: OK, I;ve found a workaround for your method.

I just RMB clicked on the share added and changed the link so that it would include login+password and it seems to be working now.